# Stackoverflow user's tag query in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How is it possible to write a query that gives the following result:

**https://stackoverflow.com/users/611696/hopstream?tab=tags**

**Given these models and relationships:**

```
User:
    has_many: questions
    has_many: answers

Questions:
    belongs_to: user
    has_and_belongs_to_many: tags
    has_many: answers

Answers:
    belongs_to: user
    belongs_to: question

Tags:
    has_and_belongs_to_many: questions
```

It should probably be in the User model, right?...

```
class User < MyModel
   def topics
      # get user's questions' topics
      # get user's answers' questions' topics
      # merge and remove duplicates
      # sort by user's activity on topic (group by of questions and answers user has posted where the question had that tag)
   end
end
```

**Or is there a much simpler way to accomplish this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion ORM of any kind is good for retrieval of records based on some (simple enough) criteria and traversing associations. For more complicated reporting stuff like this don't hesitate to use pure SQL, it's just better suited for this.

Below is untested, but should point in the right direction:

```
class User < MyModel
  def topics
    connection.execute <<SQL
      SELECT tag, count(*)
      FROM questions_tags
      WHERE question_id IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM questions
        WHERE user_id = #{id}
        UNION ALL
        SELECT questions.id
        FROM questions JOIN answers ON (question.id = answers.question_id)
        WHERE answers.user_id = #{id}
      )
      GROUP BY tag;
    SQL
  end
end
```